# magento prototype issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototype

I am not a Magento developer but I was asked to fix an issue with a Magento site.  I don't know what I'm doing with Magento, so I was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction.

The site is generating javascript errors, all of them appear to be from the prototype javascript library.

Here's the sort of errors I'm seeing.

```
var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail'); "
output: anonymous function, error on varienform.initialize , 
error on      validadtion.initialize
```

The site is at the URL http://loja.viavini.com.br/ if you want to see the errors "in action".

I'm really not sure where to start, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to post your question here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @alfasin This appears to be a generic javascript issue, and not strictly related to Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to know a thing about Magento to handle your problem.

The site you linked is using both jQuery and Prototype.  If you look at the value of `$` in the console, it's the main `jQuery` function.

```
> $
function (e,n){return new x.fn.init(e,n,t)}
```

I can't say for sure why that is, but my first area of investigation would be the multiple jQuery libraries you're including.  Near the top of the page you use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://loja.viavini.com.br/js/my_ibanner/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://loja.viavini.com.br/js/my_ibanner/jquery.noconflict.js"></script>
```

which would normally be enough to have jQuery and prototype behave together. However, later in the page you include another jQuery library

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The second jQuery redefines `$`, but doesn't re-do a call to `jQuery.noConflict()`.  This means prototype and jQuery can't co-exist on your page anymore.

The right thing to do would be determine which version of jQuery your site needs, and ensure it only includes that single library, followed by a call to the no conflict method.

The expedient thing to do would be find the insertion of the `2.0.0` jQuery, and add a no-conflict call after that — either in script block, pr via the same `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://loja.viavini.com.br/js/my_ibanner/jquery.noconflict.js"></script>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Alan Storm mentioned here are 2 more errors as well:

1) You are calling 
    `$(document).ready(function() {})` on about line 2592 - 
the `$` has to be changed to `jQuery`.

2) Also you are calling 
    `jQuery("#pikame").PikaChoose({})` on about line 3778 -
but you redefined `jQuery` (by calling the same jQuery file-on around line 67)  after pikachoose.js was called - which is overwriting the prior `jQuery` and with it "removing" `PikaChoose`.